# Run codeception on Windows system creates an Error when done like shown in the Quickstart

Tags: composer-php, codeception

Running this: `C:\Projects\HelloWorld>php vendor\bin\codecept generate:cest acceptance createTodo`

Results in the Error:

```
if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/codecept" "$@"
```

I just found the answer at the bottom of some git commentsection and wanted to make it more accessible.
https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3281
thx test1git1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to run it on windows is to run the .bat file to do all the commands and drop the "php" at the start.

`vendor\bin\codecept.bat generate:cest acceptance createTodo`