# Incorrect content of vendor/bin/codecept

Tags: codeception

I installed older Codeception 2.5 (because of module for PHP framework Yii1) like this:

```
composer require codeception/codeception:2.5.*
```

And then executed:

```
php vendor/bin/codecept run unit --coverage-html
```

And nothing happened. I can only see following code. I discovered that all 3 files (carbon, codecept, phpunit) in folder vendor/bin contain only this instead of PHP code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

dir=$(cd "${0%[/\\]*}" > /dev/null; cd '../codeception/codeception' && pwd)

if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/codecept" "$@"
```

Why is that? I am using Ubuntu 16 in Vagrant (CognacBox image). If I use XAMPP and Windows 10 it works correctly. I used Composer v1 and v2. Both with the same problem.

Comment: PS: I found other threads but people only had problems on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63917067 + https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/3281

Comment: PS2: I found no solution, but I can use different command: php vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run unit --coverage-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these codebases are no longer supported, however, if you're still interested in this approach, you can use the updated [Cognacbox 4.0](https://github.com/reddingwebpro/cognacbox) and the latest [Codeception v5](https://codeception.com/install). They both seem to fully work as expected when using current releases of these respective systems.